# Capture the return code in the same shell command

Tags: shell, zsh, alias

I want to run long running commands (30 to 40 minutes) with another command that sends an sms with the return code of the first command. E.g. `command 1; sms` where `sms` is an alias that just takes the return code of `command 1` and sends it in a text message.

How do I access the exit code of the command before `;`?

I was trying to use `$?` for it but it keeps the exit code of the previous command and not the command before `;` as that is the part of the same command.

In my ~/.zshrc file-

```
alias sms="twilio api:core:messages:create --to '+1**********' --from '+**********' --body 'exit code:$?'"
```

What I want to do:

```
~ » hello; sms
```

Sends an sms with exit code 0. Always. Need to send 1.

```
~ » hello; alias | grep sms                                                                                                                                                                              
zsh: command not found: hello                                                                                                                                                                                   
sms='twilio api:core:messages:create --to '\''+1**********'\'' --from '\''+1**********'\'' --body '\''exit code:0'\'
```

Here it should send a 1.

Comment: I think you could use `pipestatus` for this https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html

Comment: You get the `$?` of the time where the alias has been defined, not when it is executed. BTW, you would get less headache if you bury your aliases and use proper functions instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your alias looks like this:

```
alias sms="twilio --body 'exit code:$?'"
```

What happens here is that the `$?` variable is expanded in the double quotes *when the alias is defined*, but not when the alias is run. So this is identical to defining the alias as:

```
alias sms="twilio --body 'exit code:0'"
```

You can see this by using `alias sms` to print the alias after being defined:

```
% alias sms="twilio --body 'exit code:$?'"

% alias sms
sms='twilio --body '\''exit code:0'\'
```

To fix this, change the outer quotes to single quotes:

```
alias sms='twilio --body "exit code:$?"'
```

Or alternatively, use a function instead, which gets rid of the double quoting, which is generally confusing and difficult to deal with:

```
sms() {
    twilio --body "exit code:$1"
}

hello; sms $?
```

You don't need to pass `$?` as an argument here (you can use `$?` in a function too), but I found it's usually best to explicitly capture `$?` as soon as possible, because it's very easy to accidentally override by a new command.